# How to Change USB0 address of Beaglebone Black? And the ip become static when I reboot?

Tags: debian, beagleboneblack

I tried to change `/etc/network/interfaces` such that default address is `192.168.8.2` instead of `192.168.7.2` as this:

```
address 192.168.8.2
netmask 255.255.255.252
network 192.168.7.0
gateway 192.168.7.1
```

But then I am unable to access through `192.168.7.2` or `192.168.8.2`. Why?

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on which Linux distribution and especially which version of that distribution you are running on your BBB.

On official Debian images by RCN there are scripts in `/opt/scripts/` that take care of many things, including bringing up the USB network interface.

Please note that if something goes wrong you can still access the device via either the debug UART or via the USB exposed serial console.